# Where does a full node store transaction data?

Tags: monerod

When using a remote node, the node owner can see IP addresses linked to txIDs.
Running a full node means I can avoid trusting third parties and keep control over my data.
But I can't find where this data (IP & txIDs) is stored, nor if these things are.

Answer (score 0):

> the node owner can see IP addresses linked to txIDs

The remote node owner *could* (not "can") link IPs to transactions, but it would need to be using something more than just a Monero node - because a Monero node doesn't store IPs to transactions.

> Where does a full node store transaction data? ... But I can't find where this data (IP & txIDs) is stored, nor if these things are.

A node stores transactions in blocks in the blockchain database. It *doesn't* store IP addresses (other than a cache of recent network peers, *not* RPC peers).